# Working with Eclipse on two computers

Tags: eclipse

I am a student taking a Java course, and I work on two computers. I have a laptop for use in class, while at home I often use my desktop.

I would like to know if there is a way to sync code on my two computers, I would like to sync the code and resources in a project, so that it is the same thing on both my computers, and possibly with a few friends.

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I do have a Linux VPS to work with.

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).**

[GitHub](https://github.com/)'s handy and free, but you can probably find a setup for whatever system is to your taste.

As an added bonus, you get version control!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [dropbox](http://db.tt/zkrc6sz) and set your workspace on both computers to a file in drop box. It's what I do between my laptop and desktop when i go in and out of uni!! =D

Comment: Compared with a version control system, a pure file sync utility like dropbox is a bad choice. Esp. when it comes to managing source code. There is no merging capability in those file sync tools.

Comment: yer I hear what you say, I just know that dropbox is nice and simple and good for what I use it for. I bet that if you have more than one person working on it and you use visioning then dropbox is a very poor idea!